# How to choose between answer or comment?

Tags: support, comments, answers

I tried to search for this in the FAQ and in other questions, but my doubt remains.

Opening [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25305/sequential-logic) question, but happens quite frequently, I've seen that sometimes are posted comments containing what is effectively an answer to the question, even if brief (and sometimes not even that).

So i wonder if there is a policy for choosing between the two options, or what is the reason to choose to comment instead of answering.

Comment: sometimes comment = quick, poor answer

Comment: But my doubt is when the question seems requiring a simple and/or short answer, do you think that is better to add not required but related informations, or just be straightforward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think answers should be well-researched and authoritative.  If the answer is a brief one-liner or just a pointer to a website or really needs more input to confirm, I'll leave it as a comment.